# Google Pay API for Passes

Tags: php, google-pay

For creating a Google Pay loyalty card, I have been following this documentation: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api

After successfully enabling the Google Pay service API and creating service a account, the next step is:
Select your account from the list. The Account Info page is displayed - https://pay.google.com/gp/m/issuer/list.

However, I cannot find any accounts, zero accounts are listed. If I try to create an account, I get an error message, "Service account or user must be shared with an issuer."

I am not able to create a new issuer account. Has anyone any ideas on how to create one or how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Have you completed the first step?

> #### 1. Sign up
>
> [Sign up](https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/contact/instore_merchants) for Google Pay API for Passes access. After you submit the form, the support team will be in touch to validate your use case and create your Google Pay API for Passes account.

https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/contact/instore_merchants

The issuer won't appear in the list until the Google Pay team have complete reviewed and approved the sign up.